# How use a "calculated" variable in a docker-compose.yml or .env file

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

**Question** :

Can I use a "result of a bash command" as env variables in docker-compose.yml file ?

Can I "execute a command" and put the result in env variables during the "docker-compose up" ?

**The use Case :**

I work with docker & VScode in windows WSL2, and I want send "WSL2 internal IP" to my container to use Xdebug (which need a "remote_host").

The problem are the "WSL2 internal IP" can change on each reboot of the PC.

**The commande used :**

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'
```

**Where I am**

I have tested to put the command in .env file

```
MY_WSL_IP=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')
```

and the docker-compose.yml file

```
  version: "3"
    services:
      lamp_test:
        container_name: lamp_test
        image: eurelis/aws-ami-php7:php73
        volumes:
          [...]
        ports:
          [...]
        env_file: ./drupal.env
        links:
          [...]
        environment:
          - WSL_HOST_IP=${MY_WSL_IP}
     [...]
```

In this case, I get the whole command in the container.

**Notes**

When in the terminal il put play the two command in the terminal, that's work

```
export MY_WSL_IP=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')
docker-compose -f etc/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

But there is not the "use case" because variable are created "out side" the docker-compose configuration.
When using the VScode's docker plugin, I can't inject this "result"

I don't have found a proper way to inject the value in the container, nor a explicit "that's not possible".

If someone has a tips

Comment: Can you use the special host name `host.docker.internal`, without knowing its IP address?  You can also just put the name `MY_WSL_IP` in the `environment:` list without a value, and Compose will pass through the value from the outer environment into the container.

Comment: "Can you use the special host name host.docker.internal" => that are the "internal IP of windows file system". It's defined by the "docker host" process, and this IP are different from that of the WSL. --

"You can also just put the name MY_WSL_IP in the environment" => already tested, the "execution of docker command" from the VScode's docker plugin not use the environnement of the WSL. -- 

I don't have already test to expose the WSL IP in the "windows environnement", it's a new way to test.  --

Thanks